# ValueError while trying to add a prefix to the values of a dataframe column

Tags: python, pandas

I am a beginner in python.
I am trying to add a prefix to one of my columns in pandas if it meets a certain condition but i get the following error "ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

Below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'sk': [100, 234, 3333, 4569], 'lk': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})

df['sk'] = df['sk'].astype(str)

length = df['sk'].apply(len)

    if length == 3:
        df['sk'] = 'CE0' + df['sk']
    else:
        df['sk'] = 'CE' + df['sk']
df
```

Comment: I strongly recommend reading the Pandas docs. This question is quite common, had you done any research whatsoever?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36921951/truth-value-of-a-series-is-ambiguous-use-a-empty-a-bool-a-item-a-any-o)

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to:

```
df['sk'] = df['sk'].apply(lambda txt: ('CE0' if len(txt) == 3 else 'CE') + txt)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'sk': [100, 234, 3333, 4569], 'lk': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']})

df['sk'] = df['sk'].astype(str)

df['sk'] = df['sk'].apply(lambda x: f"CEO{x}" if len(x)==3 else f"CE{x}")
```

Output:

```py
   sk      lk
0  CEO100  A
1  CEO234  B
2  CE3333  C
3  CE4569  D
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
df['sk'] = df['sk'].apply(lambda x: 'CEO{}'.format(x) if len(x) == 3 else 'CE{}'.format(x))
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `np.where` and `Series.str.len`:

```
df['sk'] = np.where(df['sk'].str.len().eq(3), 'CEO' + df['sk'], 'CE' + df['sk'])

       sk lk
0  CEO100  A
1  CEO234  B
2  CE3333  C
3  CE4569  D
```

Answer (score 0):

While I do agree Lambda is a neat way to reduce the amount lines used, it might be easier do it like this:

```
def val_check(x):
    if len(x) == 3:
        return "CE0" + x
    return "CE" + x

df['sk'] = df['sk'].astype(str).apply(val_check)
```

Especially when you will be doing more complicated comparisons in the future!

Comment: You can use `.map()` for this eh, instead of `.apply()`.